# Appending templated content into parent component node

Tags: angular

I have simple child component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  template: `<div>My child Component</div>
    <ng-template #button>
        <app-my-button></app-my-button>
    </ng-template>`
})

export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() menu:ViewContainerRef;
  @ViewChild('button') buttonTemplate:TemplateRef<any>;  

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.menu){
      this.menu.createEmbeddedView(this.buttonTemplate);
    }
 }
}
```

I need to append content of 'ng-template' element to container passed from parent component.
Parent component template can has such markup:

```
<div #rightMenu></div>
<app-child [menu]="rightMenu"></app-child>
```

Here container 'rightMenu' is passed to child input attribute 'menu'.
In this code the problem is 'menu' field not has real type of ViewContainerRef. It is of type 'any'.
How we can pass container reference to child component and append template block?